# Angular - How to set multiple mat-footer in mat table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I'm trying to add multiple footer lines to mat table. Each footer with certain functions like get Minimum value from each column, get item name with minimum value in each column and count of items with value less than 10 in each column.

I managed to make an example code in below link,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multiple-footer?file=src/app/app.component.html

Here the main issue is first footer row is getting copied in lower or second and third footer row.

It will be also helpful, if someone suggest how to find item with min value and count of item with value less than 10 in each row. I managed to find minimum value in each row.

[image: expecting table like this]

Please support.

Comment: can you show an example of how exactly you want it to be?

Comment: I reedited the post with example image. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 'quick and dirty' example - the main thing to notice is that the col names for the extra footers can't be the same as used for the normal ones - then it will just use those multiple times. (Edited your functions just to show that it returns different values, as the current data returned the same values :) )

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multiple-footer-czgvn9?file=src/app/app.component.ts